# How to make Excel VBA automate clicking javascript a href link in IE

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have a macro in VBA which uses Excel to automate navigating to a web-page.

I am able to select elements by their ID and click or insert values to automate the site.

I am stuck however when trying to 'click' a link/button which does not seem to have any ID. It is a JavaScript link:

```
<div>
<table class="table" id="ctl00_cphMaster_Results" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th style="width: 70px; white-space: nowrap;" scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMaster$Results','Sort$Indicator')">True?</a></th><th class="hidden" style="width: 100px;" scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMaster$Results','Sort$Reference')">Reference</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMaster$Results','Sort$Results')">Result Number</a></th><th class="hidden" scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMaster$Results','Sort$Type')">Type</a></th><th class="hidden" scope="col"></th><th class="hidden" scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th class="hidden" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td align="center"><a href="Summary02.aspx?"><img title="Accepted" id="true" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none;" alt="Accepted" src="/Common/Graphics/tick_green.gif"></a><img id="Accepted" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none;" src="/Common/Graphics/tick_spacer.gif"><img id="Accepted" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none;" src="/Common/Graphics/tick_spacer.gif"></td><td class="hidden">MyValue</td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMaster$Results','ResultNumber$0')">ResultNumber</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I have attempted to click 'ResultNumber$0' or trigger it in some way but so far have been unsuccessful. How can I automate IE to click this javascript link/button? My code so far:

```
Sub ClickJavaLink()
Const URL = "https://myurl"    
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
    .navigate URL
    ieBusy ie
    .Visible = True

    For Each Item In ie.document.all
        If Item.ID = "QuickSearchField" Then
            Item.Value = 1
        End If
        If Item.ID = "QuickSearch" Then
            Item.Value = "MyValue"
        End If
        If Item.ID = "btnSearch" Then
            Item.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    ieBusy ie

'code working up to this point - below code is attempt to click the javascript link but does not work   
    For Each Item In ie.document.all
        If Item.ID = "ResultNumber$0" Then
            Item.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    ieBusy ie
End With
```

End Sub

Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub

Comment: Welcome to SO! you should provide your relevant macro code.  you should probably take a minute to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  it is a useful guide!

Comment: Posting a bigger snippet of the HTML code would help. Is that `anchor` element inside a `div` maybe? You can still get this element using `ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")(i)` where `i` is the element's index in the collection of all `anchor` elements.

Comment: Hi Stavros, thanks for your reply, i have added more of the HTML code, there was a lot of it so I have tried to capture the bit that, as far as i can tell, relates to the section I am trying to automate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better, faster, way. Use an [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) css selector with contains operator

```
ie.document.querySelector("[href*='ResultNumber$0']").click
```

Single line; no looping; reduced code complexity.

Comment: Nowadays, I usually go for selenium.

Comment: you are most welcome. Once you get used to css selectors you rarely want to swop back to other methods.

Comment: Indeed very elegant. +1

Comment: @StavrosJon Thank you. For me css selectors make life so much easier (most of the time! I can hear some eyeballs rolling and murmurs of pain in the web dev back benches).

Answer (score 1):

You can reach the anchor elements by first accessing the table which conveniently enough has a unique `ID`.

Here's how you can loop through all anchor elements inside that table:

```
Dim anc As HTMLAnchorElement
For Each anc In ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_cphMaster_Results").getElementsByTagName("a")
    Debug.Print anc.innerText
    'anc.click 'uncomment this to click on all links
Next anc
```

For demonstration purposes the above code prints the text of these elements in the immediate window.

To access a specific element you can use the element's index. For example to access the first  element in the table you can do it like so:

```
ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_cphMaster_Results").getElementsByTagName("a")(0).click
```

To access the second one you just replace `0` with `1` and so on.

Another way to access a specific element would be to use its `href` attribute:

```
Dim anc As HTMLAnchorElement
For Each anc In ie.document.getElementById("ctl00_cphMaster_Results").getElementsByTagName("a")
    If anc.href = "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMaster$Results','ResultNumber$0')" Then
        Debug.Print anc.innerText
        'anc.click
    End If
Next anc
```

You will need to add a reference (VBE>Tools>References) to `Microsoft HTML Object Library`.

Comment: Hi Stavros, thanks for your response, apologies, are you able to show how this should fit in with my code to work? I have tried to copy your code into mine but nothing seems to happen. I have enabled the reference to microsoft HTML object library.

Comment: @jpmtozer you have to add the reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library`. See the last sentence of my answer. In your VB editor go to tools then references and check the reference and hit ok

Comment: @jpmtozer so you got rid of the "User defined type..." error? What's the problem then?

Comment: Hi Stavros, I managed to get it working however the line "ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_cphMaster_Results").getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click" i commented out of the code, and it worked, not sure why this would be?

Answer (score 0):

You can try locating the `href` element on the page like this :

```
For Each item In Ie.Document.getAttribute("href", 2)

   If item.href ="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMaster$Results','ResultNumber$0')" Then

      item.Click

         Exit For

   End If

Next item
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: `href` is not a tag name. It's an attribute.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, unfortunately this did not work. There was no debug error, the code ran through to the end but no action was taken and IE remained on the same page.

Comment: Good point @StavrosJon - code edited to use `getattribute` instead - The 2 tells it to return a string. @jpmtozer - try the updated code

Comment: I have updated the code but receive an error on the For Each line: Run time error 438 object doesnt support this property or method.

Comment: @Nick `.getAttribute` method would return a string. Plus this method is not supported by the HTML Document object.