# Why is VBA throwing Run Time Error 438 when using querySelector to click link on website?

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, browser-automation

I am trying to navigate through a website using a VBA macro. I have been successful so far adapting my code off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48920039/10728777), but have come upon a situation where I need to click on a "logout" link that does not have an ID or Name when I inspect it (for reference, see below:)

[image]

Through some searching, it seems that the preferred method to find and direct VBA to click on this link is using querySelector. I've found various similar questions (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57907692), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935046/vba-to-click-on-a-button-in-ie-with-no-id-name-classname), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823118/clicking-on-an-html-element-with-queryselector-thru-vba#), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62307064/trying-to-interact-with-a-link-in-ie-using-vba)) which direct how to use it.

As a test, I simply tried the below to see if it would work:

```
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'log in, click on various elements here

    Set logoutButton = ie.document.queryselector("*")
    MsgBox logoutButton
```

Unfortunately, VBA throws Run Time Error 438 on the querySelector line, and I'm unable to understand what it is that I'm doing incorrectly.

I have added the following references to VBA:

[image: vba references]

Could someone let me know what it is I'm missing that's causing this error? Additionally, is this the method that I should be using to click the link?
Thanks!

EDIT: @QHarr has been helpful with finding out why I'm getting this issue: it's a problem with the emulation settings on Internet Explorer. querySelector will only work with document mode 9 and beyond, but my IE is defaulting to 8.

Even when I change the mode to 9 (and enable the Persist Emulation setting), it appears that my IE still opens with 8 and only changes to 9 when I check on the document mode. This causes me to still get the same error, unless I manually pause my code, check the document mode, then rerun the code.

Comment: Which OS version are you using and what is the emulation mode setting for internet explorer?

Comment: @Qharr I'm using Windows Server 2012, Version 6.2 (Build 9200). How do I find which emulation mode setting I'm using?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-faq

Comment: @QHarr maybe I'm not following - my vba code appears to open Internet Explorer v 11.0.9600.20296 and does not seem to be Edge emulating a version of Internet Explorer

Comment: @QHarr  I understand that IE is no longer supported by MS and is being phased out - I have not yet updated to Edge. Should I update?

Comment: You can use same instructions with IE to find emulation setting in browser. Your current wildcard css selector I would expect to match the root (document) node.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for the clarification - I'm using Document mode 8 via X-UA-compatible HTTP header

Comment: Change the mode to higher if possible to enable querySelector

Comment: @QHarr I changed it to every higher option available and enabled the Persist Emulation setting but I am still getting the same error. I have the option to switch to 9, 10, or Edge.

Comment: Is the automated browser launching with that same setting? Or is it defaulting to prior setting?

Comment: One way to test if this is the reason is to put the `STOP` command before the attempt to use querySelector then in the launched browser check the emulation mode, if <= 8 then set to higher than 8 and press F8 to execute next code line within the code pane of VBE and see if error still occurs.

Comment: Worse case scenario, you either automate setting document mode or use a different method to target the node or even execScript to execute the associated javascript. There are plenty of options here.

Comment: @Qharr it appears that if I set the mode to 9 in a previous window, the automated browser initially launches with 8 but switches to 9 when I check the emulation mode. If I stop the code, then check the emulation mode, then continue the code, it runs fine. Is there a way to force the automated browser to initiate in 9?

Comment: @Qharr if you post the information we chatted about as an answer to my post, I will happily mark it as the answer to my question :)

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: @QHarr - No, I wasn't able to force the automated browser to initiate in 9. However, you _did_ help me find out why querySelector wasn't working, so I appreciate that. If you know how to set the emulation mode in VBA, I would appreciate that also :)

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector` will throw an exception if nothing is selected. Try right clicking the element and copying the css selector. Or you can write your own.

`table.LoginDialog td > a:nth-child(2)` might work.

It's worth setting a break point on the selector and testing them out in the Immediate window.

Comment: Couple of questions about your answer: 1) Shouldn't using the wildcard make querySelector find something? I thought that by using the wildcard, it should find something if it is working. 2) Since my code is throwing an error saying that InternetExplorer.Application doesn't support querySelector as a method, I don't think that it's even attempting to use querySelector yet, and that there's something else going wrong.

Comment: @Salvaria you're right - I assumed error 438 was "Object required" (which is what is thrown when nothing is found). Since you've added a reference to MS Internet Controls, try making use of early binding and `Dim ie As New InternetExplorer`.

Comment: @Salvaria your error `InternetExplorer.Application doesn't support querySelector` is interesting as you're not calling that method on it. You're calling it on `Document`.